# I have a column in my dataset, eventDate (2000-01-01T00:06:00). How do I split them into date and time?

Tags: r, lubridate

```
pt$eventDate <- as.Date(pt$eventDate)
pt$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(pt$eventDate),format="%H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/Kolkata")
```

`as.Date` function did its job.

A time column got created too, all of it just filled with 5H 30H 0S, any idea what the mistake could be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time component is lost after doing `pt$eventDate <- as.Date(pt$eventDate)`. Try this -

```
pt$Time <- format(pt$eventDate,format="%T")
pt$eventDate <- as.Date(pt$eventDate)
```

Comment: Cheers man. I used pt$eventDate = ymd_hms(pt$eventDate) and then ran pt$Time <- format(pt$eventDate,format="%T"). It has given me a different column with the time in it but the eventDate column still has both the date and time.